# How to generate invoice numbers with a combination of customer codes without duplicates and sequentially with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Dear All Master,

How to generate invoice numbers with a combination of customer codes without duplicates and sequentially with VBA.
so the position in "C2" is the customer code.
So the "serial" will change continuously in order with the customer code. Does it need invoice numbers stored in their own sheets so that they make it easier for duplicates and sequential to occur? if necessary how?. Please recommend the best solution

in "C4" is the combination invoice number.

JS : COMPANY NAME

12 : MONTH

22 : 2 DIGIT YEAR

XX : CUSTOMER CODE

001 : SERIAL

EXAMPLE

JS-12-22-10-001

JS-12-22-10-002

JS-12-22-11-001

JS-12-22-11-002

[image: SAMPLE INVOICE-2]

```
Sub generatenumberinvoice()
Sheet1.Range("c3").Value = Sheet1.Range("c3").Value + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I think you need a separate sheet with a table as the main data. For example the table has columns as follow: Date, Inv. Number, Customer Name, Item, Qty, Price, etc. Each time there is a transaction, it has to be inputted to this table. Then the next Inv. Number can be generated by reading the last inv number in the column "Inv. Number" in that table. And I think the format of the Inv. Number should be something like this : JS-YY-MM-DD-xxx in order it can read the max Inv. Number (the last inv. Number) in "Inv. number" column in that table.

Comment: @karma , Thank you for your reply. Actually, this is only for invoice numbering so the transaction is not saved and then how to please guide from the VBA code

Comment: Why are the serial numbers in the example 10-01,10-01,11-01,11-02 and not 001,002,003,004 ?

Comment: Malf, maybe try like this : `With Range("C4")` ... next line 
`.Value = Left(.Value, 12) & Format(Right(.Value, 3) + 1, "000")` ... next line `end with` . Each time you run this sub, it will add 1 to the last three digit number. For example current C4 value is "JS-12-22-11-002". After you run the code, C4 value will be "JS-12-22-11-003"

Comment: @karma I think you also need to check the month-year and reset to 001 if not the same as current date.

Comment: @CDP1802, you are correct. Just like you, I also wonder what is the 10 and the 11 ? is it a date ? Anyway .... `With Range("C4")` ..... `curDate = Format(Date, "mm-yy-dd-")` .... `invDate = Mid(.Value, 4, 9)` .... `If invDate <> curDate Then: dt = curDate: num = "001"` ....  `Else: dt = invDate: num = Format(Right(.Value, 3) + 1, "000")` ... `End If` .... `.Value = Left(.Value, 3) & dt & num` .... `End With`. If Malf doesn't want to reset if date is different then just use `num=` in the `else` ... this will change the date and the number still continue (not reset to 001).

Comment: @CDP1802 , `Why are the serial numbers in the example 10-01,10-01,11-01,11-02 and not 001,002,003,004 ?` sorry I was late replying so the result is like  `JS-12-22-10-001 JS-12-22-10-002 JS-12-22-11-001 JS-12-22-11-002` this because the one posted was wrong and now it has been corrected

Comment: @CDP1802 , `I think you also need to check the month-year and reset to 001 if not the same as current date.` so actually the one in "c4" it is a combination with the formula so it will automatically generate "12-22" if it is input date in "B1".

Comment: @karma , Thank you for the answer from you.  `, I also wonder what is the 10 and the 11 ? ` so the position in "C2" is the customer code.   sorry I was late replying so the result is like `JS-12-22-10-001 JS-12-22-10-002 JS-12-22-11-001 JS-12-22-11-002` . From the VBA code your answer is date so it should be the customer code.

Comment: Malf, I don't think it's doable if you don't have a record of the previous invoices number for each customer code. You say : _the "serial" will change continuously in order with the customer code_. So it's impossible to get the next number if for example the user change the customer code from 10 to 11, then how to know what is the next invoice number of customer with a code 11 ? Except if it doesn't care about what month/year/customer-code (ignoring 12 characters from left) whatever they are, the number will keep on increase based on what is read on the last 3 digits in cell C4.

Comment: @karma , please guide me so that I can have record of the previous invoices number for each customer code as you said

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly help you, but maybe you can have a look and modify it according to your case.

1. Make a new workbook
2. Rename Sheet1 into TABLE, Sheet2 into DATA, Sheet3 into FormInput
3. Type on each sheet **exactly** like in the picture below. For the time being, ignore the INPUT button which seen in the image of sheet FormInput
4. In the Name Manager, create a named range *CustID* which refers to:
   `=OFFSET(TABLE!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(TABLE!$A:$A),2)`
5. Create another named range : *data* which refers to:
    `=OFFSET(DATA!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(DATA!$A:$A),4)`
6. Create another named range : *trans* which refers to :
    `=OFFSET(FormInput!$A$6,0,0,COUNTA(FormInput!$A:$A)-4,1)`
7. Finally, copy the formula below and paste it to cell B3 of sheet FormInput
    `=IF(COUNTIF(INDEX(data,,3),"*JS-"&TEXT($B$1,"yy-mm-")&VLOOKUP($B$2,CustID,2,FALSE)&"*")<>0,"JS-"&TEXT($B$1,"yy-mm-")&VLOOKUP($B$2,CustID,2,FALSE)&"-"&TEXT(AGGREGATE(14,6,RIGHT(INDEX(data,,3),3)/(LEFT(INDEX(data,,3),12)="JS-"&TEXT($B$1,"yy-mm-")&VLOOKUP($B$2,CustID,2,FALSE)&"-"),1)+1,"000"),"JS-"&TEXT($B$1,"yy-mm-")&VLOOKUP($B$2,CustID,2,FALSE)&"-001")`

[image]

Try to type aaa (the name of customer) in cell B2 sheet FormInput. If everything above done correctly, cell B3 will show *JS-22-12-10-001*. Type bbb then it show *JS-22-12-11-001*, type ccc then it show *JS-22-12-12-001*. The last 3 characters always show 001 (which means this is the first invoice number of Dec-22 for whatever id), because there is no data in sheet DATA. Hence it just show 22-12 depends on the date seen in cell B1, and -10 or -11 or -12 depends on the name of the customer seen in cell B2.

Try to change the date to something like 21-nov-22. Cell B3 will show 22-11 and the CustID depends on the name seen in cell B2, and the number always show "001". Play around by changing the date of different month and change the name (aaa or bbb or ccc) so you understand thoroughly how it works.

Now, fill data in sheets DATA **exactly** like the image below
[image]

Back in FormInput, fill the date with Nov-22 month and fill the cust name with aaa, cell B3 will show the next invoice number: *JS-22-11-10-006* because the formula read the data that the last number for id 10 in Nov-22 is *JS-22-11-10-005*, so the formula add 1 to the serial number in cell B3 for id 10 (customer aaa in this case).

Still in November date, type bbb for cust name. It will show *JS-22-11-11-001* in cell B3 because there is no data for id 11 of Nov-22. So this is the first invoice number of Nov-22 for id 11 (customer bbb in this case).

Now change the date to December date, then type aaa for cust name. Cell B3 will show  the next invoice number for id 10 in Dec-22 is *JS-22-12-10-002*, because the formula see that the last number in the data for id 10 of Dec-22 is "001".

Still in December date, 
type ccc for cust name. Cell B3 will show *JS-22-12-12-004*.
type bbb for cust name. Cell B3 will show *JS-22-12-11-001* which means this is the first invoice number for id 11 in Dec-22.

Play around by filling a different invoice number in sheet DATA then fill the date and the name of the cust in sheet InputForm.

The INPUT button seen in InputForm is a vba code to input the data seen in InputForm into sheet DATA. But this is another case, and if you want to know it, I think you'd better open another question.

Thank you.

Thanks to Mr. Peter_SSs, because I get the formula for cell B3 from him in this [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/looking-for-max-of-a-range-of-numbers-in-strings.1068272/post-5130977)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry I was late reply