# how to export pdf file from excel when the file name already exists then there is a messagebox yes / no with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

how to export pdf file from excel when the file name already exists then there is a messagebox yes / no with VBA ?

please recommend so that with the message box I can choose whether yes or not to replace it and another one "cust" this is a subfolder I want there to be a messagebox too if not found the subfolder.

Thanks

```
Sub PrintToPDF()
Dim strFilename     As String
Dim rngRange        As Range
Dim cust     As Range
Dim strcust As String

Set cust = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
Set rngRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4")
strcust = cust.Value
strFilename = rngRange.Value
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "D:\test inv\" & cust & "\" & strFilename & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ActiveSheet To PDF (`Dir`)

```vb
Sub ActiveSheetToPDF()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "ActiveSheet To PDF"
    Const INITIAL_FOLDER_PATH As String = "D:\test inv\"
    
    ' Reference the active sheet.
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Build the initial folder path.
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim iPath As String: iPath = INITIAL_FOLDER_PATH
    If Right(iPath, 1) <> pSep Then iPath = iPath & pSep
    
    Dim TestName As String: TestName = Dir(iPath, vbDirectory)
    
    If Len(TestName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The initial path '" & iPath & "' doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
    ' Retrieve the folder and the file name.
       
    Dim BaseName As String, FolderName As String
       
    With sh.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        FolderName = CStr(.Range("B2").Value)
        If Len(FolderName) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The cell with the folder name is blank.", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        BaseName = CStr(.Range("C4").Value)
        If Len(BaseName) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The cell with the file base name is blank.", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
        
    ' Build the folder path.
        
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = iPath & FolderName & pSep
    TestName = Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory)
    
    Dim MsgAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    If Len(TestName) = 0 Then
        MsgAnswer = MsgBox("The folder '" & FolderName _
            & "' doesn't exist in '" & iPath & "'." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Do you want it created?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_TITLE)
        If MsgAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        Dim ErrNum As Long
        On Error Resume Next
            MkDir FolderPath
            ErrNum = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ErrNum <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "The path '" & FolderPath & "' couldn't be created.", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
        
    ' Build the file path.
        
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FolderPath & BaseName & ".pdf"
    TestName = Dir(FilePath)
    
    If Len(TestName) > 0 Then
        MsgAnswer = MsgBox("A file named '" & TestName _
            & "' already exists in '" & FolderPath & "'." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Do you want to overwrite it?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_TITLE)
        If MsgAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Export.
    sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FilePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Sheet '" & sh.Name & "' printed to PDF.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer from you went very perfectly

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74799037/how-to-generate-invoice-numbers-with-a-combination-of-customer-codes-without-dup?noredirect=1#comment132013240_74799037) I have another post related to vba maybe you can help me